# Angular 2+ / Ionic 2+ passing data to child component not binding

Tags: angular, ionic3, parent-child

Hi I'm trying to pass data from parent to child to its child component, From parent to child is working fine but from child to its child isn't displaying anything (UI not updated?).

Ionic parent page (comments.ts):

```
...
export class CommentsPage {

  selectedFeedPost: FeedPostModel
  selectedGroupId: string

  commentsList: CommentModel[]

  constructor(private _viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    if (this.navParams.data && this.navParams.data.feedPost && this.navParams.data.groupId) {
      this.selectedFeedPost = this.navParams.data.feedPost
      this.selectedGroupId = this.navParams.data.groupId

      // The rest will be handled in the custom comments components
      this.commentsList = this.selectedFeedPost.comments // Don't have to check again, should only be able to access when feed post has comments.
    }
  }
}
```

Ionic page view (comments.html):

```
...
<ion-content padding>
  <!-- Custom component for holding comments, passing an array of comments to child component -->
  <comments-list *ngIf="commentsList" [commentsList]="commentsList"></comments-list>
</ion-content>
...
```

Child custom component (comments-list.ts):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comments-list',
  templateUrl: 'comments-list.html',
  inputs: ['commentsList']
})
export class CommentsListComponent implements OnInit {

  // Used to capture the passed through data from a parent component.
  commentsList: CommentModel[]

  // Used to bind to the UI
  displayList: CommentModel[] = []

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Component initialization function, first function to be triggered when component is called/loaded/entered.

    // Transform [Object object] to Array of objects, for binding
    for (let i in this.commentsList) {
      this.displayList.push(this.commentsList[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Child custom component HTML (comments-list.html):

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding #itemSlide *ngFor="let comment of displayList">

    <!-- Custom component -->
    <comment-thumbnail [comment]="comment"></comment-thumbnail>

    <ion-item-options>
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="alert"></ion-icon>
        Report
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="danger">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        Delete
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

*** Until here everything is working fine. ***

The child of child view doesn't display anything while there is data.

Child of child custom component (comment-thumbnail.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';

/* Models & interfaces */
import { CommentModel } from '../../models/comment.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'comment-thumbnail',
  templateUrl: 'comment-thumbnail.html',
  inputs: ['comment']
})
export class CommentThumbnailComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  // Used to capture the passed through data from a parent component.
  @Input() comment: CommentModel

  item: CommentModel

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.comment)
    this.item = this.comment
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.comment)
    this.item = this.comment
  }
}
```

Child of child custom component view (comment-thumbnail.html):

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img src="{{ item.created.by.photoUri }}">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{ item.created.by.name }}</h2>
  <p>{{ item.message }}</p>
  <ion-note item-end>
    {{ item.created.at * 1000 | date:'MMM d, y, h:mm a' }}
  </ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

Chrome console output:

[image]

There's nothing showing up in the view but the data is logging in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Use ChangeDetectionStrategy https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Thank you :) I'll give it a try purely for science. I've decided I'm not going to need a single comment as re-usable component so got rid of the child of child one.